# PPTP ping client to client error

Tags: networking, centos, vpn

I installed pptp server on a centos 6 64bit server

- PPTP Server ip : 55.66.77.10
- PPTP Local ip : 10.0.0.1
- Client1 IP : 10.0.0.60  centos 5 64bit
- Client2 IP : 10.0.0.61  centos5 64bit

PPTP Server can ping Client1 And client 1 can ping PPTP Server
PPTP Server can ping Client2 And client 2 can ping PPTP Server

**The problem is client 1 can not ping Client 2** and i get this error also on PPTP server error log `Cannot determine Ethernet address for proxy ARP`

Ping from Client2 to Client1

```
PING 10.0.0.60 (10.0.0.60) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 10.0.0.60 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5000ms
```

`route -n` on PPTP Server

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.60       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.0.0.61       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp1
55.66.77.10     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         55.66.77.19     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

`route -n` On Client 1

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0        255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
55.66.77.10     70.14.13.19    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         70.14.13.19    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

`route -n` On Client 2

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
55.66.77.10     84.56.120.60    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         84.56.120.60    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

`cat /etc/ppp/options.pptpd` on PPTP server

```
###############################################################################
# $Id: options.pptpd,v 1.11 2005/12/29 01:21:09 quozl Exp $
#
# Sample Poptop PPP options file /etc/ppp/options.pptpd
# Options used by PPP when a connection arrives from a client.
# This file is pointed to by /etc/pptpd.conf option keyword.
# Changes are effective on the next connection.  See "man pppd".
#
# You are expected to change this file to suit your system.  As
# packaged, it requires PPP 2.4.2 and the kernel MPPE module.
###############################################################################


# Authentication

# Name of the local system for authentication purposes 
# (must match the second field in /etc/ppp/chap-secrets entries)
name pptpd

# Strip the domain prefix from the username before authentication.
# (applies if you use pppd with chapms-strip-domain patch)
#chapms-strip-domain


# Encryption
# (There have been multiple versions of PPP with encryption support,
# choose with of the following sections you will use.)


# BSD licensed ppp-2.4.2 upstream with MPPE only, kernel module ppp_mppe.o
# {{{
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
# Require the peer to authenticate itself using MS-CHAPv2 [Microsoft
# Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol, Version 2] authentication.
require-mschap-v2
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
# (note that MPPE requires the use of MSCHAP-V2 during authentication)
require-mppe-128
# }}}


# OpenSSL licensed ppp-2.4.1 fork with MPPE only, kernel module mppe.o
# {{{
#-chap
#-chapms
# Require the peer to authenticate itself using MS-CHAPv2 [Microsoft
# Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol, Version 2] authentication.
#+chapms-v2
# Require MPPE encryption
# (note that MPPE requires the use of MSCHAP-V2 during authentication)
#mppe-40    # enable either 40-bit or 128-bit, not both
#mppe-128
#mppe-stateless
# }}}


# Network and Routing

# If pppd is acting as a server for Microsoft Windows clients, this
# option allows pppd to supply one or two DNS (Domain Name Server)
# addresses to the clients.  The first instance of this option
# specifies the primary DNS address; the second instance (if given)
# specifies the secondary DNS address.
#ms-dns 10.0.0.1
#ms-dns 10.0.0.2

# If pppd is acting as a server for Microsoft Windows or "Samba"
# clients, this option allows pppd to supply one or two WINS (Windows
# Internet Name Services) server addresses to the clients.  The first
# instance of this option specifies the primary WINS address; the
# second instance (if given) specifies the secondary WINS address.
#ms-wins 10.0.0.3
#ms-wins 10.0.0.4

# Add an entry to this system's ARP [Address Resolution Protocol]
# table with the IP address of the peer and the Ethernet address of this
# system.  This will have the effect of making the peer appear to other
# systems to be on the local ethernet.
# (you do not need this if your PPTP server is responsible for routing
# packets to the clients -- James Cameron)
proxyarp

# Normally pptpd passes the IP address to pppd, but if pptpd has been
# given the delegate option in pptpd.conf or the --delegate command line
# option, then pppd will use chap-secrets or radius to allocate the
# client IP address.  The default local IP address used at the server
# end is often the same as the address of the server.  To override this,
# specify the local IP address here.
# (you must not use this unless you have used the delegate option)
#10.8.0.100


# Logging

# Enable connection debugging facilities.
# (see your syslog configuration for where pppd sends to)
debug

# Print out all the option values which have been set.
# (often requested by mailing list to verify options)
#dump


# Miscellaneous

# Create a UUCP-style lock file for the pseudo-tty to ensure exclusive
# access.
lock

# Disable BSD-Compress compression
nobsdcomp 

# Disable Van Jacobson compression 
# (needed on some networks with Windows 9x/ME/XP clients, see posting to
# poptop-server on 14th April 2005 by Pawel Pokrywka and followups,
# http://marc.theaimsgroup.com/?t=111343175400006&r=1&w=2 )
novj
novjccomp

# turn off logging to stderr, since this may be redirected to pptpd, 
# which may trigger a loopback
nologfd

# put plugins here 
# (putting them higher up may cause them to sent messages to the pty)
```

`cat /etc/ppp/options.pptp` on Client1 and Client2

```
###############################################################################
# $Id: options.pptp,v 1.3 2006/03/26 23:11:05 quozl Exp $
#
# Sample PPTP PPP options file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
# Options used by PPP when a connection is made by a PPTP client.
# This file can be referred to by an /etc/ppp/peers file for the tunnel.
# Changes are effective on the next connection.  See "man pppd".
#
# You are expected to change this file to suit your system.  As
# packaged, it requires PPP 2.4.2 or later from http://ppp.samba.org/
# and the kernel MPPE module available from the CVS repository also on
# http://ppp.samba.org/, which is packaged for DKMS as kernel_ppp_mppe.
###############################################################################

# Lock the port
lock

# Authentication
# We don't need the tunnel server to authenticate itself
noauth

# We won't do PAP, EAP, CHAP, or MSCHAP, but we will accept MSCHAP-V2
# (you may need to remove these refusals if the server is not using MPPE)
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap

# Compression
# Turn off compression protocols we know won't be used
nobsdcomp
nodeflate

# Encryption
# (There have been multiple versions of PPP with encryption support,
# choose which of the following sections you will use.  Note that MPPE
# requires the use of MSCHAP-V2 during authentication)
#
# Note that using PPTP with MPPE and MSCHAP-V2 should be considered
# insecure:
# http://marc.info/?l=pptpclient-devel&m=134372640219039&w=2
# https://github.com/moxie0/chapcrack/blob/master/README.md
# http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2743314

# http://ppp.samba.org/ the PPP project version of PPP by Paul Mackarras
# ppp-2.4.2 or later with MPPE only, kernel module ppp_mppe.o
# If the kernel is booted in FIPS mode (fips=1), the ppp_mppe.ko module
# is not allowed and PPTP-MPPE is not available.
# {{{
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
#require-mppe-128
# }}}

# http://mppe-mppc.alphacron.de/ fork from PPP project by Jan Dubiec
# ppp-2.4.2 or later with MPPE and MPPC, kernel module ppp_mppe_mppc.o
# {{{
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
#mppe required,stateless
# }}}
```

`IPtables` is stopped on clients and server, Also `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` is enabled on PPTP Server.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue? i'm facing the problem of same sort...

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/423695/cannot-determine-ethernet-address-for-proxy-arp-on-pptp) post on SF about the same issue.  It boils down to an issue of netmasks on the clients.